# How can I pull somebody with just a payer order 9 in payer order column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

| CustomerID | payerorder | payername |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | 1 | root |
| 00001 | 2 | spade |
| 00001 | 9 | ginny |
| 00002 | 1 | spade |
| 00002 | 3 | root |
| 00002 | 9 | ginny |
| 00003 | 9 | ginny |

Result I would like to have:

| CustomerID | payerorder | payername |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 000003 | 9 | ginny |

I am trying to pull customers that only have a payer order 9 payer name ginny, they can not have any other payer order attached to them. The issue I am running into is all customers have a payer order 9 payer name ginny. As you can see the billing order is not always a simple 1-8 listing, as depending how it is put into the system, they may not use billing order 2 but skip to billing order 3. How would I go about grabbing just customers with billing order 9 payer name ginny? I would say the ginny isnt needed in the sql due to payer order 9 will always be payer name ginny.

I did try doing:

```
WHERE payerorder < 9 AND payername is NULL
```

Which ended up not working, it would only pull one row that had a payer order but a blank payer name but the customer, when I checked the profile, still had other payer orders like 1,3,5 with payer names.

I also tried:

```
payerorder = 9 and payername = ginny
```

But the issue with that is everybody has payer order 9 payer name ginny. I only need to pull customers who only have payer order 9 and payer name ginny.

Edit: [new post with updated information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77446569/how-can-i-pull-somebody-with-currently-just-a-payer-order-9-in-payer-order-colum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method would be to use an `EXISTS` to check no rows for that client exist with a value other than `9`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       YT.CustomerID,
       YT.payerorder,
       YT.payername
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
WHERE YT.payerorder = 9
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.YourTable E
                  WHERE E.payername= YT.payername
                    AND E.payerorder <> 9);
```

An alternative method would be with a `HAVING` to check the `MIN` and `MAX` values are both `9`:

```sql
SELECT MAX(YT.CustomerID_,
       MAX(YT.payerorder) AS payerorder,
       YT.payername AS payername
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
GROUP BY YT.payername
WHERE MAX(YT.payerorder) = 9
  AND MIN(YT.payerorder) = 9;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is a window function, this is most useful if you want the full row of payer order 9, not just aggregations.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      count = COUNT(CASE WHEN t.payerorder <> 9 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY t.CustomerID)
    FROM dbo.YourTable t
) t
WHERE t.count = 0;
```