# How can I pull somebody with currently just a payer order 9 in payer order column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I made a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77439671/how-can-i-pull-somebody-with-just-a-payer-order-9-in-payer-order-column) yesterday and realized a few things after the fact I posted it. In how our system is set up they have 'hidden' feature on the page the information is being pulled from. The hidden information is payer name that has expired from current date and backwards, which is causing the issue of not showing current only ginny payer names but just showing anybody who has only ever been just ginny payers. I need to show the current people too. Here is the code I used that came from the original post.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       YT.CustomerID,
       YT.payerorder,
       YT.payername
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
WHERE YT.payerorder = 9
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.YourTable E
                  WHERE E.payername= YT.payername
                    AND E.payerorder <> 9);
```

The answer the person provided is technically correct for what I asked at the time so I did vote it correct.

Here is what is actually going on:

| CustomerID | payerorder | payername | PayerEndDate | Hidden |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | 1 | root |  |  |
| 00001 | 2 | spade |  |  |
| 00001 | 9 | ginny |  |  |
| 00002 | 1 | spade |  |  |
| 00002 | 3 | root |  |  |
| 00002 | 9 | ginny |  |  |
| 00003 | 9 | ginny |  |  |
| 00004 | 3 | root | 06/30/2023 | Yes |
| 00004 | 9 | ginny |  |  |

Result I would like:

| CustomerID | payerorder | payername | PayerEndDate | Hidden |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00003 | 9 | ginny |  |  |
| 00004 | 9 | ginny |  |  |

Result with sql I have been given:

| CustomerID | payerorder | payername | PayerEndDate | Hidden |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00003 | 9 | ginny |  |  |

**Please note `hidden` is not a field in the table, i am just showing the issue with the hidden feature and how it works.**

Technically even though 00004 has an 'old' payer name which is hidden on the page I am pulling from, it is currently a ginny only payer since the payer name root expired 06/30/2023 since we are using the current date (11/08/2023).

I also need to clarify how the set up actually is rather than just trying to make it simple because I am not sure I am implementing it right with what I was given.

My sql looks like this for the set up:

```
SELECT 
   "CUSTOMERPAYER"."payerorder",
 "CUSTOMER"."client_id",
   "PAYER"."payername",
 "CUSTOMERPAYER"."PayerEndDate"
FROM "dbo"."CUSTOMER" AS "CUSTOMER"

LEFT OUTER JOIN "dbo"."Payer" AS "PAYER"
ON (
   "CUSTOMER"."payer_id" = "PAYER"."payer_id"
)
LEFT OUTER JOIN "dbo"."CUSTOMERPAYER" AS "CUSTOMERPAYER"
ON (
   "CUSTOMER"."customerpayer_id" = "CUSTOMERPAYER"."customerpayer_id"
)
```

I tried the first sql listed above and only pulled customers who only ever had ginny payer name, it did not consider people who are currently ginny payers that had a 'old' payer name which is not used anymore. I did tried editing the sql that was given to me but I kept running into errors because I thought if I did another subquery within the subquery I could filter out the not in use anymore payer names by date. I was expecting current ginny payers with and without 'old' payer names that are not in use anymore.

Comment: Then change the `WHERE` in the `EXISTS` appropriately. Take the time to *understand* the solution you have been given.

Comment: it should be as simple as adding `AND PayerEndDate is null` or whatever to both side of exists?

Comment: @ThomA do you have anything in particular you recommend for understanding the solution? Like a website? I looked around yesterday to gain an understanding of what is going on and I was left with more questions than answers.

Comment: [`EXISTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) would be a start.

Comment: @siggemannen are you saying to add it to the outside of sub query where and the inside of the sub query where as well? just trying to understand you.

Comment: i think both. but it's hard to understand your actual data, if all rows have this column set to something, but it's not current. you should display the *actual* data, if you want actual help

Comment: @siggemannen which column?

Comment: PayerEndDate i guess

Comment: @siggemannen from what I am seeing if there isn't a date selected it's just null.

Comment: @ThomA here is my takeaway from what you answered on my previous post. the outside of the subquery where payerorder = 9 is grabbing the 9th payerorder in the list. the not exist is returning payerorder that has no billing order 1-8? is this correct?